# Why do I get this error: "Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)."

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I wrote code. But I cannot understand why this error occurs:

> Maximum stored procedure, function, trigger, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)

Can I use trigger in that case or do I need to change trigger for example output?

```
CREATE TABLE shop1
(
    GoodsID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    price int,
    orderdate datetime2 DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

CREATE TABLE shop2
(
    GoodsID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    price int,
    orderdate datetime2 DEFAULT GETDATE()
);

CREATE TABLE shopglobal 
(
    GoodsID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    price int,
    orderdate datetime2 DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    region NVARCHAR(100)
);

CREATE TRIGGER trig_SHOP1
ON [SHOP1]
FOR INSERT, DELETE, UPDATE
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) 
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO shopglobal (price, orderdate, region) 
            SELECT i.price, i.orderdate, 'shop1' 
            FROM Inserted i
    END

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted) 
       AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM inserted)
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM shopglobal
        WHERE GoodsID IN (SELECT deleted.GoodsID FROM deleted)
    END   

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM inserted) 
       AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM deleted)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE shopglobal
        SET price = inserted.price,
            orderdate = inserted.orderdate
        FROM shopglobal
        INNER JOIN inserted ON shopglobal.GoodsID = inserted.GoodsID AND region = 'shop1'
    END;
```

Comment: Do you have a trigger on the `shopglobal` table that then inserts/updates/deletes rows in the `shop1` table?

Comment: You've probably got some form of recursion, i.e. trigger 1 fires trigger 2 which fires trigger 1. I debug that by adding a print statement in the trigger and carrying out an update which fires the first trigger.

Comment: I add one more triggers and errors stayed

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69284930/i-get-this-error-maximum-stored-procedure-function-trigger-or-view-nesting?noredirect=1#comment122458862_69284930

Answer (score 0):

Do you have other triggers on your tables?
They may be triggering each other until "Maximum stored procedure, function, **trigger**, or view nesting level exceeded (limit 32)."

The solution is to check for nesting level in your triggers

```
IF TRIGGER_NESTLEVEL() > 1
 RETURN
```

This article provides a good explanation
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1713/maximum-stored-procedure-function-trigger-or-view-nesting-level-exceeded-limit-32/